# Google Map : Can we add a link to get directions from current location?

Tags: google-maps

Here's what I would like to do :
http://www.google.com/maps?start=geolocalize_me&destination=some address here

Google would know that the keyword "geolocalize_me" means that it should geolocalize the person and adds the direction afterwards.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) and the [directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService), along with [HTML5 geolocation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/geolocation/trip_meter/). You shouldn't try to link directly to directions in maps.google.com as parameters are undocumented and subject to change.

Here's a [sample](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) that uses geolocation to find a users current position.